# Stack Exchange API quota is intermittently unstable

Tags: bug, api

The `quota_remaining` returned by the Stack Exchange API is intermittently unstable and either increases or decreases significantly for no apparent reason.

For example, my `quota_remaining` increased by 10 and then decreased by 20.

SmokeDetector is also experiencing this. For SmokeDetector, there appear to be two separate `quota_remaining` numbers being tracked by the servers. One, which is most often reported in the request response and decremented by the quota used for most requests, has rolled over for the new 24 hour period. The other `quota_remaining` number did not roll over into the new 24 hour period and continues to decrement from the quota for the prior 24 hour period. The one which has not rolled over into a new 24 hour period (i.e. hasn't reset the `quota_remaining`) is returned substantially less often than the one which has rolled over to the new 24 hour period. The two `quota_remaining` numbers are different by many thousands of requests.

Comment: As has been mentioned, we're also experiencing this with SmokeDetector. What we're seeing could be consistent with one, or more, servers not resetting the `quota_remaining` when it was reset by the others. We're seeing what looks like two independent `quota_remaining`  numbers being reported (i.e. separately decremented), with the one which has not been reset being used much more rarely. That's consistent with, probably, a single SE API server getting out of synchronization wrt. the remaining quota.

Comment: @rene for SD, the two `quota_remaining` numbers are different by many thousands of requests (i.e. the entire number of requests made the prior 24 hour period). Basically, one server didn't reset at the end of the 24 hour period.